# Platform-extension-specific replacement for volatile-specifier as hardware-register access without compiler optimizations?

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded, c++20, volatile

In C++20 and further the volatile-specifier for variables is largely deprecated. Embedded developers using GCC have been relying on this (flawed) specifier for a long time. The concept that side-effects can occur in a code-graph, unclear by C++ statements put down in code, is not a good C++-core-language-standard idea. GCC implements it's own version of the C++ language and gives the volatile-specifier a big meaning. Is there any GCC-specific way (maybe in the works???) to properly mark a C++ object as "do not unreasonably assume content"? I am largely interested in natural C++-language-driven assignment operations, even compound. I am aware that the deprecation was made due to historical problems of mis-interpretation across compilers and MCU/CPU instruction generations and thus we are not criticizing the C++ standard itself.

Comment: "*In C++20 and further the volatile-specifier for variables is largely deprecated.*" Were they? My understanding is that certain *uses* of `volatile` variables were deprecated, but you can still declare and manipulate them. "*gives the volatile-specifier a big meaning*" Does it? What "big meaning" is that?

Comment: @NicolBolas For the first point I would like to mention that deprecation does not yet mean removal, please see https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2139r1.html#3.5 . For the second point I would like to refer to the "embedded" keyword applied to this question and this relates to a big industry with many developers relying on certain hardware semantics that just happened to work using compilers that implement volatile in a MCU compatible way. Please note that "implement" may not mean "according to core C++ standard" but "according to platform needs".

Comment: @rplgn Look at the C++20 changes here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv#Notes - can you justify using any of the deprecated cases?

Comment: I guarantee you that G++ will have a way to write code for hardware registers, because G++ is used for embedded code and its developers know that. They won't remove the feature.

Comment: Deprectated uses was not used mostly anyway (maybe except increment/decrement). `volatile` as type specifier is NOT depricated.

Comment: @RichardCritten: I cannot but I find that the wording "discarded-value expression" is a peculiar exclusion to allow a lot of embedded uses for the volatile specifier. I find that those uses are properly discouraged. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @user253751 I have followed online discussions and have used the GCC compilers for my projects. The momentum of the C++ standard seems to be concerning me a lot, so much that I am asking if there is anything else planned that further clarifies the meaning that the volatile specifier has today.

Comment: Some of the deprecations have been un-deprecated again: https://wg21.link/p2327

Comment: @sklott: That is true! I just hope that the C++ language does take a strong stance on compatibility with the expectations from experienced, established industrial software developers. The turmoil that had happened is discouraging. The GCC developers' words on this matter have not reached me, if even spoken (it is where what volatile stands for matters the most popularly). I was confused by a GCC 11.2.0 compiler warning with GNU++2a standard setting but it contradicts the exclusion I mentioned previously... But it is fine if things don't change and volatile persists!

Comment: If you read orifinal proposal for deprecation, then first point there is: *Continue supporting the time-honored usage of volatile to load and store variables that are used for shared memory, signal handling, setjmp / longjmp, or other external modifications such as special hardware support.*

Comment: @rplgn: "*The turmoil that had happened is discouraging.*" What "turmoil" is going on? If there's "turmoil", maybe the people in the middle of that could submit a proposal to the C++ committee explaining what the issues are and what "expectations from experienced, established industrial software developers" are at play. Like right here, you've only spoken in nebulous terms, without showing any code or even anything hypothetical that you're concerned about.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I would like to mention compound CPU instructions (for example SBI on AVR) that could naturally be mapped to compound GCC volatile operations. I am not sure whether under the current C++ standard momentum the compilers be discouraged to perform compound operations since under the current wording the use of assignment-operation-results is deprecated. I am not using nebulous terms because the C++ language is moving in an uncertain direction.

Comment: @rplgn: But bitwise compound operators [were undeprecated](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2327r1.pdf). Which was mentioned further up the thread. Also, this has nothing to do with `volatile` *itself* being deprecated, which it was not. So you should correct the question to focus on the specific kinds of things you're talking about, not some general sense that `volatile` is going away so you should switch to something else.

Comment: @rplgn: "*I am not using nebulous terms because the C++ language is moving in an uncertain direction.*" Is it though? I don't see what is "uncertain" about it. I mean, all this stuff is public knowledge, and the process for suggesting changes is open. So what precisely is "uncertain" here?

Comment: @NicolBolas: the purpose of volatile is uncertain given the historical use of it, mentioned in the post. I see https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2327r1.pdf but the exclusion of just bitwise-operations seems like a hack. But I welcome it, given the current situation that C++ is used in. It is a bad idea to keep using volatile if it is at expense of a good foundation for the core C++ language, as shown by the de-deprecation. To me the scientific argument is lacking, especially trying to teach the C++ language. I expect the C++ language community to find better grammar.

Comment: @rplgn: "*the purpose of volatile is uncertain given the historical use of it*" What is "uncertain" about its "purpose"? The proposal for deprecating certain uses of `volatile` objects explains what its purpose is intended to be. I don't know how it could be "uncertain" if the intended purpose has been clearly stated. And indeed, the use case you outline seems to fit within the intended use cases for `volatile`. So I don't really understand what is "uncertain" here.

Comment: @NicolBolas: You are being very technical here, ignoring the arguments about language improvement. Our argument is divided on the language outlook. Let me try to convince you from a linguistical perspective. The operations concerning volatile are a subset of the operations without volatile. Therefor in the computational sense volatile is unnecessary, it is a no-op, doing nothing. But the specialness of platforms that make use of volatile give it meaning, split by compilers. Having a definition different by compiler is _not clearly stated_. So why keep such a troublesome feature?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251356/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-rplgn).

Comment: You cannot write hardware-related programming without `volatile` and anyone who has ever done so understands why. If someone is yapping about concurrency and memory barriers etc in the context of `volatile`, their reasoning has already derailed - such things were never what `volatile` was intended for. So using `volatile` for such purposes is not "deprecation", since it has never been a valid use of `volatile` in the first place. The keyword predates multicore CPUs and multithreading by some ~20 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any GCC-specific way (maybe in the works???) to properly mark a C++ object as "do not unreasonably assume content"?

That's what `volatile` *means*. The need for such a syntactic construct is one of the main reasons why `volatile` still exists. Indeed, the [very proposal that introduced deprecating certain operations on `volatile` values has this as one of its primary goals](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1152r0.html#prop):

> Continue supporting the time-honored usage of volatile to load and store variables that are used for shared memory, signal handling, setjmp / longjmp, or other external modifications such as special hardware support.

So the tool you are looking for is still called `volatile`. All that has changed is that a few operations on `volatile` objects have been removed. Not only has there been no declared intent to remove `volatile` in its entirety from the language, there is a clear recognition that it is a useful tool.

---

> GCC implements it's own version of the C++ language and gives the volatile-specifier a big meaning.

This is incorrect. `volatile` is not a magic flag that tells the compiler to just do whatever. Indeed, it is quite the opposite: it tells the compiler that it *cannot* just do whatever. It forces the compiler to issue loads and stores as required by the literal text of the code, even if the compiler cannot see any way that a second load could possible get a different value.

As pointed out above, `volatile` is a versatile tool which can be used with a variety of constructs that are closely associated with specific hardware. Memory-mapped IO registers can be read through a `volatile` object whose address is assigned to the address of the MMIO register. While the mapping of that object to that address may require input outside of the C++ standard, the way you say that you want `volatile` behavior is *part* of the standard.

That is, let's say that you're writing code that you want to be portable to two different devices. They both have a MMIO register that does basically the same thing, but they live at different addresses. When you build for each device, you assign the variable the appropriate memory address, perhaps via platform-specific macros or other build commands. But the code you write that accesses them is the same, because `volatile` isn't platform-specific.

`volatile` is a platform-neutral tool that allows you to *access* platform-specific stuff. There's no reason to have every compiler roll its own way of saying, "I will read from and write to this memory location as your code literally says".

Comment: Thank you for participating in my thought-experiment. You have clearly elaborated the rationale behind volatile, which is what I deeply wished for. In retrospect I should not have been so provocative. There is still a different approach I would prefer for the language, but you can leave that out-of-scope for answering. Wish you well!